# In Get-Mailbox, (Exchange 2010) why would the servername change and how can I correct it?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, dag, email

I have a 4 node DAG in 2 sites.  All databases are mounted in Site 1.

For some reason the "servername" property in "get-mailbox" is causing an issue with MAPI based software such as Goodlink.

Specifically, the servername property has the name of the mailbox servers located in the remote site.  MAPI poxying is not configured between the two sites.  No MAPI communication should ever go to the remote site.

Right now many users have the servername set in a site that is different than where the mailbox is actually mounted (which server the mounted DAG DB is on)

**Question**

- Does the servername property of get-mailbox affect MAPI connections?
- Why does it change for users in a DAG?
- How can I make the MAPI property servername correct?

Answer (score 1):

I can't find the exact blog article I'm thinking of, but [this one](http://blogs.technet.com/b/appssrv/archive/2014/03/10/get-mailbox-does-not-reflect-the-correct-servername-for-mailboxes-on-databases-for-a-dag.aspx) is close. [This](http://blogs.technet.com/b/timmcmic/archive/2011/09/26/exchange-2010-homemta-and-msexchhomeservername-are-not-updated-on-mailboxes.aspx) is another Technet blog that talks about that property. I ran into this problem when decommissioning Exchange 2010 Mailbox Servers. Even with the server removed gracefully, the property remained set to a non-existent server. I can say for a fact this won't affect end-user access.